# Array to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have an array like this :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "action"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "depot"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Demandeur"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "Particulier"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Nom"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Cheval"
  }
```

But I want an associative array, to access it like this : $_REQUEST['Nom'] and have in return 'Cheval' etc...

The first array is actually an object, created with jQuery and here is his construction :

```
jQuery('input:submit').click(function() {
    var itemMetaArray = {};
    jQuery('.frm_pro_form :input:not(:hidden, :submit)').each(function() {
        if(jQuery('#field_demande').val() != undefined){
            itemMetaArray['action'] = jQuery('#field_demande').val();
        } 
        else itemMetaArray['action'] = jQuery('#field_demande2').val();
        var label = jQuery(this).closest('.frm_form_field').find('.frm_primary_label').text().trim();
        if(jQuery(this).attr('name').indexOf("file") == -1 ) {
            itemMetaArray[label] = jQuery(this).val();
        }else{
              var fileName = jQuery(this).attr('name');
              fileName = fileName.substring(0,fileName.length-2);
              itemMetaArray[label] = fileName;
        }
});
```

After this, I do some parsing in PHP :

```
$dataInfo = explode(",",$_POST['dataInfo']);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataInfo); ++$i){
    $tmpWithoutBrackets[$i] = trim($dataInfo[$i],"{..}");
    $tmpWithoutColon[$i] = explode(":",$tmpWithoutBrackets[$i]);
    for($j = 0; $j < (count($tmpWithoutColon) + 1); ++$j){
        $arrayFinal[$i][$j] = trim($tmpWithoutColon[$i][$j],"\"");
    }
    $arrayFinal[$i] = array_diff($arrayFinal[$i],array(""));
}
```

$arrayFinal is the same array as arrayInfo

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: post your code effort and your expected outcome

Comment: Show us how you create the first array. That is where your issue is, and that is where the fix should be applied

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: I update my post :)

Comment: @Nathan30, check if my answer works for you.

Comment: I suggest that you create the array as you want it in the jquery code

Comment: @AbhayMaurya I answer your post, thanks a lot

Comment: @RiggsFolly I heard that associative array doesn't exist in jQuery

Comment: @Nathan30, associative arrays are called object in jQuery, more like in javascript as jQuery is mere library of js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your array like this:

```
$test = array('arrayInfo' => array(array('Nom','Cheval'),array('Prenom','Nathan'),array('Adresse postale','4 impasse Molinas')),'arrayFile' => array(array ('application/pdf','3a514fdbd3ca2af35bf8e5b9c3c80d17','JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFuZyhmci1GUikgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDI2IDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnVlPj4vTWV0')));

$result = array();
foreach($test as $k=>$t){
    $count = 0;
    $_key = '';
    $_value = '';
    foreach($t as $f){
        foreach($f as $final){
            $count++;
            if($count%2!==0){
                $_key = $final;
            }
            else{
                $_value = $final;
            }
            if($_value!==''){
                $result[$k][$_key] = $_value;
                $_value = '';
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $result['arrayInfo']['Nom'];//Cheval
```

For your modified question, answer will be a little changed ofcourse:

```
    $test = array(array('Nom','Cheval'),array('Prenom','Nathan'),array('Adresse postale','4 impasse Molinas'));

$result = array();
foreach($test as $k=>$t){
    $count = 0;
    $_key = '';
    $_value = '';
    foreach($t as $final){
        $count++;
        if($count%2!==0){
            $_key = $final;
        }
        else{
            $_value = $final;
        }
        if($_value!==''){
            $result[$_key] = $_value;
            $_value = '';
        }
    }
}
var_dump($result);
echo $result['Nom'];//Cheval
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: No problems, just take care that your `[arrayFile][0]` has three values, while it should have only two as `[arrayInfo]`. Possible typo. Happy Coding!

Comment: I update my first post, because it wasn't clear after reflexion.. Actually I need to do the same as your answer, but not on the same array. I try to modify your code, but without success..

Comment: @Nathan30, I have updated my answer to suit your current question.

Comment: This is not exactly the same array as me. Mine is more like : "array(array("nom","cheval"))" so I have an error at the third foreach...

Comment: @Nathan30, My bad, updated the answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: No problem :) Happy Coding!